# Why do I needs login to access published data in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'd like to use Google Cloud Storage as image saver. I added "allUsers" on the rights.
I referred this page.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

I can access the image from any account of logged in on google. But when I logout from google. I can't see the image. When I click the image of link, it's redirect to google login page.

Is it possible to access to the image without login?

ex: https://storage.cloud.google.com/image_maker_media/layout/square.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Link to publicly readable objects using one of these:

- https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/object_name
- https://BUCKET_NAME.storage.googleapis.com/object_name

For example, your resource: http://storage.googleapis.com/image_maker_media/layout/square.png

Comment: Thank you!! Thank you!! The problem was coursed by my access link!